# Celery Task class with DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery

I tried using Celery Task & Django rest framework serializer in same class with multiple inheritance.

```
from celery import Task
class ReceiveSerializer(Task, serializers.Serializer):
    def run(self, source, *args, **kwargs):
        self.save()
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        # call long running save method
```

I got error,

```
  File "<>\serializers.py", line 217, in <module>
    class ReceiveSerializer(Task, serializers.Serializer):
  File "<>\workspace\www\lib\site-packages\celery-3.1.20-py2.7.egg\celery\app\task.py", line 199, in __new_
_
    tasks.register(new(cls, name, bases, attrs))
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

The save method has to create long list of objects in db (some times more than 5 minutes). I don't want user to wait for long time.
Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be possible using a Mixin?

```
class YourMixin:
    # if you want to trigger the task on save:
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ret = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        some_task.apply_async((
            self.__class__.__name__,
            self.pk,
        ))
        return ret


@task()
def some_task(model_name, model_id):
    my_model = apps.get_model('django_app_name.{}'.format(model_name))
    obj = my_model.objects.get(pk=model_id)
```